# От .fla + .as к Flex: как мигрировать проект?

Tags: ide, flash, миграция, apache-flex

Построил Air проект в Adobe Flash, AS3, однокадровые мувиклипы, ООП.
Задумываюсь о переводе его во Flex, разрабатывать дальше в Flash Builder или FDT (Eclipse). С Flex и упомянутыми IDE опыт нулевой.

**Как перевести проект?**

Пока смутно представляю себе процесс. Вроде бы, придётся отделить весь код от мувиклипов в библиотеке. Придётся ли полностью отказаться от флешевой графики, переделав её в статичные изображения? Допустимы ли многокадровые клипы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видно на глаз следующие последствия:

- да, код придется отделять, и практически полностью переписывать (например потому что во flex он полностью event-ориентированный)
- флешевую графику можно оставить, например перенести ее в SWF формате внутрь интерфейса flex проекта (png/jpg тоже можно, если нравиться),(компоненты: s:Image, s:SWFLoader)
- технически графику можно полностью не трогать, создав проект Flash Pro во Flash Builder
- исходя из предыдущего пункта, многокадровые movieclips допустимы, просто они не вписываются в идеологию flex
- помните что, размер flex проекта существенно больше, причем в разы, начинается с 300-500кб
- переход на flex полностью оправдывает себя при сложных, насыщенных интерфейсах в приложении

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! О переходе задумался, т.к. проект на 97% — код (около 50 классов), и лишь 3% отрисованный интерфейс, детали которого не принципиальны. Размер не важен, т.к. это Air приложение для Desktop'а.

Comment: Если вы рассматриваете свой проект не как анимационно-дизайнерский, то переход на полноценную IDE (FB, FD)очень удобен и практичен.